# How to add URL to your favorites in Windows Phone & how to cache the data in mobile HTML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caching

I am trying to find  a solution to cache the data in Windows Phone. But I could not able to find  a solution, I am new developer and how can I add the URL to favorites in Windows Mobile which I want to save in favorites.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly: You are asking "How to save the browsed URLs programmatically?"

You can use the Navigating Navigated events of WebBrowser control to get the details of the current URL being navigated, and so you can store it.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentUrl = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
}
```

Comment: no i want to add the url to browser favourites in windows phone

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to save URLs from your app into IE's favourites list.  The only app with access to that list is IE itself.  Sorry.